# How do I rewrite a PIC32 boot flash via code?

Tags: c, pic, pic32

I have an application that needs to rewrite my bootloader on a PIC32 device. After I disable interrupts, I try to erase 0x1fc00000 with NVMErasePage, but it does not erase, and NVMErasePage return a good status. How can I erase the boot flash from code?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on these things but, there is a register with a boot flash write protect bit, search the PIC32Mxxx/2xx data sheet for this.

DEVCFG0: DEVICE CONFIGURATION WORD 0

Check that out.

Comment: It appears I can not write this bit from code,and it it set to writable, the manual says  says it is programable.